# Showing a text timer that counts seconds in A-frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

So I'm having some trouble getting a timer into my A-frame game. I'm using the  component and want it to update every second, like a normal game timer. I can display the text fine, but can't seem to figure out how to measure the game time.

```
<a-text id="score" value="hits" position="-0.2 -0.6 -1" color="red" width="5" anchor="left"></a-text>
$("#score").setAttribute("text","value","hits "+score)
```

I update the score text like this and that works, but how to get time from game start and use that to update another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is through setInterval like:

```
var time = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  timeText.setAttribute('text', 'value', `${time} seconds`);
  time++;
}, 1000);
```